# The End of XA-Transaction, Garbage Collection and till-tx-complete =true

Tags: java, oracle, transactions, garbage-collection

Having the following problem of understanding why a connection session exists that goes on for 6 hours and also holding a lock and breaking the thread the question is rased if a connection of XADataSource (Oracle driver) needs a Java reference at all to be kept alive.

In terms of distributed transaction set to kept till it is explicitly ended (keep-xa-conn-till-tx-complete=true) I wonder how a driver could decide wether to close connection and commit a transaction once the GC recycled the connection. Is there even a way for the DBMS to do so?

So the question goes how does a DBMS decide wether to abandon a distributed transaction or not.

Comment: If you want to see it from Oracle's side check views dba_2pc_pending and v$transtaction. If you need help please describe your situation in detail. There is nothing simple when it comes to distributed transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DBMS does not decide to end the transaction, the transaction manager does.

The transaction manager is set up to run in your application containers, whether they are Spring, J2EE application servers, or something else. They have to "know" they are distributed transaction managers by being configured correctly. In a distributed transaction environment, where you have multiple transactional applications and/or services interacting to complete a transaction, they must all be able to support distributed transactions to make proper use of the XADataSources and send the right signals up and down the chain for commit vs rollback.

Presuming that you have the above situation, multiple applications and/or services participating in a distributed transaction, it sounds as if one of them is not configured correctly. Something in the chain is not truly a distributed transaction, so that when it completes it's only completing locally and not sending the signal back down the line. So the distributed transaction never completes, holding the connection open.

Check the configuration of every application and/or service participating in the transaction. Add logging output on each that details whether the transaction is a distributed one or not. If you can't do that, then dd logging output to each that records the start and end of the transaction. Find the latest point in the sequence of actions where you see an open-transaction but not a close-transaction. If you see that, it's likely the node right after it in the chain that is doing something wrong.

Good luck.

Comment: The time out of the XA connection is set to 10 hours. I guess this is what made the problem possible at all.